# Different results between Python shell and IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter, python-idle

The following code is printing the sum of multiples of 5 from 1 to 1000

```
s = 0
for i in range(1, 1001):
    if i % 5 == 0: s += i
print(s)
```

If I run this code in IDLE, the result is 100500, but in the shell there's an error **SyntaxError: invalid syntax**, coming out at `print`. Why do IDLE and shell give different results? My Python version is 3.7.

Comment: Are you simply typing the code in at the shell (rather than running it from a file)?  If so, you need to enter a blank line before the `print` to terminate the preceding multi-line statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python shell (canonical name: REPL) you're expected to terminate an indented block with an empty line, so you should run this in REPL:

```
s = 0
for i in range(1, 1001):
    if i % 5 == 0: s += i

print(s)
```

Note the empty line before `print`, that's required in REPL but not when you run the code from a file (or IDLE).

Comment: IDLE's Shell also requires a blank line.  The difference is that IDLE auto-indents the 3rd line, so one would have to backspace to enter `print` without an indent, making it a separate statement.